# gaps between faces using micropolygon displacement

Tags: displacement

Why do i have these gaps between faces using micropolygon displacement?

[image]

here is the unwrap
[image]

thank you.

Comment: It looks like you extruded from individual faces instead of extruding region and shrinking/fattening along normal. Can you zoom in and confirm that you haven't created plateaus there?